# Initializing the input field with URL query sting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

I have an input field that needs to be filled by URL query string, the page name is "track".

Code for input:

```
<div class="page-width">
<h1 class="small--text-center">{{ page.title }}</h1>

<input type="text" id="trackid" name="tracking" placeholder="Tracking ID">

<button type="button" onClick="changeChannel();">Locate My Item</button>
```

The URL is:
`mysite.com/pages/track?trackid=123`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please make your request clearer. Do you want to initialize the input field with the value of the url query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this if I understand you meaning well:

```
<div class="page-width">
<h1 class="small--text-center">{{ page.title }}</h1>

<input type="text" id="trackid" name="tracking" placeholder="Tracking ID">

<button type="button" onClick="changeChannel();">Locate My Item</button>

<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var name = 'trackid'; // if your url is mysite.com/pages/track?trackid=123
var url = window.location.href;
document.getElementById("trackid").value = getParameterByName(name, url);
</script>
```

This code will initialize the input field with the trackId value in url query string.

Comment: "approve the edit"? am sorry new here so not sure what that means. I marked your response as an answer.

Comment: I edited your question to be more clearer and you should approve the edit that it can be applied. I think you can find the edit notification in the top right of the page.